# Is there a specific way to describe over-grown, old, tough vegetables?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

One term that seems maybe suit­able is *over­ripe*, but this seems to be
spe­cific to fruits which when over­ripe ex­hibit dif­fer­ent changes
com­pared to those of veg­eta­bles: over­ripe fruit de­struc­ture and
de­com­pose, but the veg­eta­bles that I’m look­ing for an ad­jec­tive for
of­ten be­come tougher, woody per­haps, more dif­fi­cult to chew, etc.

So it’s not so much that they’re over­ripe be­cause these qual­i­ties may
es­sen­tially pre­vent it from even prop­erly ripen­ing.

I also like *over­grown*, but that usu­ally de­scribes veg­e­ta­tion that
has grown out of con­trol, so over­load­ing the mean­ing of this word seems
prob­lem­atic due to the over­lap­ping con­text.

An ad­jec­tive I usu­ally do see used for this is *old*, but that doesn’t
seem to re­ally cap­ture the con­cept specif­i­cally enough.

Maybe *late har­vest* or *past due*? These com­pounds do the job to
de­scribe it but seem not straight­for­ward to use in a sen­tence like
ad­jec­tives are nor­mally used.

Comment: What sort of context would you want to use it in? I'm just thinking there isn't a common word for it, so the word you use might vary depending on the context.

Answer (score 6):

### **picked past their prime** (*also*) peak

> - When harvested **past their prime**, beets have a strong taste and a tough, pithy texture"
>     ([Google Books](https://books.google.it/books?id=hv8jDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA234&lpg=PA234&dq=%22past%20their%20prime%22%20vegetables%20tough&source=bl&ots=4GB2K0mZws&sig=ACfU3U3VE0NZnzIAq-QXecCFQPQiRqOjVQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjI4fKdgMHkAhXGJ1AKHdN8DCoQ6AEwCXoECBMQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22past%20their%20prime%22%20vegetables%20tough&f=false))
> - *Here are some ways that you can use your frozen, **past-prime** fruits and vegetables.*
> - *Tomatoes that are **past their prime** can be pureed and frozen for up to 6 months.*
>     (*[Frugal Living Mom](https://www.frugallivingmom.com/using-produce-when-its-past-its-prime/)*.com)
> - *The Pilgrims may have eaten turnips, but why should we? Let's face it; the turnip can be a tricky vegetable. If they're even a day or two **past their prime**, you'll wind up dining on a veggie that tastes more like a piece of wood than an appetizing holiday side.*
>     (*How Stuff Works*.com)
> - When florets [broccoli] on the outside edge of the head are large and full, this is another helpful indicator that you’re good to go. But don’t wait too long. When they begin to turn from green to yellow, this is a sign that they’re beginning to flower, and **past their peak**.
>     ([Gardener's Path.com](https://gardenerspath.com/plants/vegetables/grow-broccoli/))

A single-word alternative could be

### overmature

> **overmature**: past the age or condition of maturity
>   **a** : beyond the stage of desirable or optimal development or productivity
>
> - *overmature wax beans*
> - *The squash is very tender and should be handled with care to prevent skin cuts and bruising. Avoid purchasing any with … a dull, shriveled skin, which is a sign of **overmaturity**.*
>     ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overmature))

Comment: *Past their prime* is a fine answer, one you can certainly use to describe
produce grown a bit “long in the tooth” out in the field and so was
harvested past its peak point of biological development for culinary
desirability. However, in some context-free situations it might possibly be
understood as meaning something slightly different: that once-fresh produce
sat around somewhere too long **after** harvest, whether languishing
unconsumed on the greengrocer’s shelves or on your own, or from having been
stored too long in a darkened root cellar or the vegetable drawer of your fridge.

Comment: See also [past their peak](https://books.google.com/books?id=hv8jDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA234&lpg=PA234&dq=vegetables+past+their+peak&source=bl&ots=4GB2K2g2Bw&sig=ACfU3U2nmBPONmRA3f8uZ--Nwd3t7DKxIg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwifxZi6tsHkAhVDbKwKHQOeCtYQ6AEwF3oECAoQAQ#v=snippet&q=past%20peak%20prime&f=false) in *The Mother Earth News Guide to Vegetable Gardening* now that Hærfestmōnað is upon us come. :)

Comment: @tchrist thank you for the tip, when I have time, and with your blessing I'll add that variant too. By the way, I added "picked" because I was  aware that "past its prime" could also refer to  (withered or wilted) veggies and fruit that have been stored too long, adding "picked" or "harvested" overcomes that problem.

Answer (score 5):

The scientific term for this process is **senescence**.

This word encompasses the aging of plants in general.  It describes not only the phase that fruits and vegetables enter after their ripening phases, but also the process by which leaves turn colors in the autumn, etc.

[This is the wikipedia article on the process of senescence.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plant_senescence)

The adjective form of the word is [senescent](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/senescent).

> Showing signs of the farmer's neglect, the fields were filled with overgrown vines and vegetables in various states of senescence.

Comment: Leafy vegetables are said to have _gone to seed_ when they produce a flower stalk which takes energy from the leaves that we want to eat and makes them tough.

Comment: Just to mention, "senescent" is a pretty scientific word which most people aren't familiar with, so I wouldn't use it except in an academic context.

Comment: @wjandrea senescent is definitely a $2 word, but it means aged in common parlance.  Similar origin to the word senile.   The scientific term derives from that sense of the word.

Comment: @KateBunting That is certainly true.  But, that's part of their senescence.

Answer (score 0):

***Run to seed*** could also work in this context -

## Run to seed

> To become old and decrepit. Plants that are allowed to set seed after
> flowering either become bitter to the taste (lettuce) or will not
> bloom as well the following year (daffodils, tulips). Henry Fielding
> used the term figuratively in an essay of 1740: “For Virtue itself by
> growing too exuberant and . . . by running to seed changes its very
> nature.”

([thefreedictionary.com](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+to+seed))

Answer (score 0):

For a number of vegetables, the word you're looking for is **bolted**. [Bolting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolting_(horticulture)) is

> the production of a flowering stem (or stems) on agricultural and horticultural crops before the crop is harvested, in a natural attempt to produce seeds and reproduce. These flowering stems are usually vigorous extensions of existing leaf-bearing stems, and in order to produce them, a plant diverts resources away from producing the edible parts such as leaves or roots, resulting in a poor quality harvest. Plants that have produced flowering stems in this way are said to have bolted.